# PS Object unescape character

Tags: powershell

I have small error when running my code. I assign a string to custom object but it's parsing the string by itself and throwing an error.

[image: error msg]

Code:

```
foreach ($item in $hrdblistofobjects) {
    [string]$content = Get-Content -Path $item
    [string]$content = $content.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")
    #here is line 43 which is shown as error as well
    foreach ($object in $listofitemsdb) {
        $result = $content -match $object
        $OurObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ObjectName     = $null
            TestObjectName = $null
            Result         = $null
        }
        $OurObject.ObjectName = $item
        $OurObject.TestObjectName = $object #here is line 52 which is other part of error
        $OurObject.Result = $result
        $Resultsdb += $OurObject
    }
}
```

This code loads an item and checks if an object exists within an item. Basically if string part exists within a string part and then saves result to a variable. I am using this code for other objects and items but they don't have that `\p` part which I am assuming is the issue. I can't put $object into single quotes for obvious reasons (this was suggested on internet but in my case it's not possible). So is there any other option how to unescape `\p`? I tried  `$object.Replace("\PMS","\\PMS")` but that did not work either (this was suggested somewhere too).

EDIT:

```
$Resultsdb = @(foreach ($item in $hrdblistofobjects) {
        [string]$content = Get-Content -Path $item
        [string]$content = $content.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")

        foreach ($object in $listofitemsdb) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ObjectName     = $item
                TestObjectName = $object
                Result         = $content -match $object
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: [1] PLEASE do not use pictures of text. you have the error as text ... paste it into your Original Post _as text_. ///// [2] where does `$listofitemsdb` come from? your code does not run since you fail to post a minimal but _complete_ example of your code problem. ///// [3] you have not provided any sample data - that means everything acts on your sample data is entirely unverifiable. PLEASE include the needed data to make it possible to test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the match part to this and it's working fine `$result = $content -match $object.Replace("\PMS","\\PMS")`.

Sorry for errors in posting. I will amend that.

Answer (score 0):

`$Resultsdb` is not defined as an array, hence you get that error when you try to add one object to another object when that doesn't implement the addition operator.

You shouldn't be appending to an array in a loop anyway. That will perform poorly, because with each iteration it creates a new array with the size increased by one, copies all elements from the existing array, puts the new item in the new free slot, and then replaces the original array with the new one.

A better approach is to just output your objects in the loop and collect the loop output in a variable:

```
$Resultsdb = foreach ($item in $hrdblistofobjects) {
    ...
    foreach ($object in $listofitemsdb) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ObjectName     = $item
            TestObjectName = $object
            Result         = $content -match $object
        }
    }
}
```

Run the loop in an array subexpression if you need to ensure that the result is an array, otherwise it will be empty or a single object when the loop returns less than two results.

```
$Resultsdb = @(foreach ($item in $hrdblistofobjects) {
    ...
})
```

Note that you need to suppress other output on the default output stream in the loop, so that it doesn't pollute your result.

Comment: I rewrote my code and added it to the post. I still experience the same issue. Did I understand your advice incorrectly?

Comment: @Jakub It's clearly not possible that your modified code would give you the same error. If you're still getting an error: please [edit] your question and show it.

Comment: Yes, you were correct addinf this part "$Resultsdb = @" resulted in it throwing one error instead of original two. I was more looking to solve the other error but thank you for this as well !